# I need to make an account generator for a site but i have some problems with the request payload

Tags: forms, python-requests, grpc, payload

The registration window requires name, surname, email, password. There is an example of the form [image: registration form]

and the request payload format like this
[image: request payload]

What is this type of format and how can i make requests using this format without getting errors? If i try to make requests using the same format but changing only email, password, name and surname i get a grpc-message in response headers saying: "grpc: received message larger than max (1551183920 vs. 4194304)" and the account generation doesn't work.

This is the request i make:

```css
import requests

url = "https://grips-web.aboutyou.com/checkout.CheckoutV1/registerWithEmail"

payload = "H\\u0008\\u009f\\u0005\\u0010\\u0004\\u001a\\u001abillyjhon22@gmail.com*\\u0007Billy2\\u0007Jhonson8\\u0002J\\u000f\\n\\rhelloworld122!\\u0021P\\u0001"
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/grpc-web+proto",
    "accept-language": "it-IT,it;q=0.9"
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Sample code of how you are connecting to the gRPC server, how you are constructing and sending the gRPC requests would be useful.

Comment: yeah sorry i updated it @EaswarSwaminathan

Answer (score 0):

Give the `application/grpc-web+proto` `Content-Type`, I assume that's a JavaScript client using [gRPC-Web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) to submit requests (through a proxy) to a gRPC service.

gRPC uses binary-encoded messages on-the-wire for efficiency (and HTTP/2) and so it's more challenging to hand-craft messages directly.

Usually, you'd use the protobuf (schema) file to generate e.g. a Python client for you and this would expose a class that you could use to (un)marshal messages.

It's possible to hack messages directly but it's challenging.

- Have a look at Marc Gravell's [Protobuf Decoder](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode) as that may help.
- You may be able to decode the JavaScript imports used by the browser client to reverse-engineer the protobuf services|methods. gRPC-Web uses gRPC just not HTTP/2. So, the sames RPCs and messages will work with the proxy and server directly.
- You could then compile Python libraries directly. You'd need to identify the origin server too as you'd need to then send gRPC over HTTP/2 directly to it rather than gRPC-Web calls against the proxy.
- It's possible the gRPC service owners restrict access to the backend to the gRPC-Web client either by IP, some auth mechanism and|or other means.

> **NOTE** Generally, if the proto isn't published, the service owners don't intend the service to be used in ways other than available.